# How do i get Contents of an ASPX file through java?

Tags: java, asp.net, web-scraping

In java, is there any way to get the content of a webpage, wich is an .ASPX file.
I know how to read/write anything from a normal HTML page, but asp pages seem to have one URL for multiple pages, so it's not really possible to reach the desired page by URL.

I understand you can't/won't give me complete instructions right here, but could you maybe send me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about ASPX pages compared to any other type of page; "plain" html pages could have been dynamically generated as well.

Just don't forget that the query string is also part of the URL. Many ASPX, PHP, etc pages might not even be 'correct' to request without some query string value at all. And other sites don't have file extensions at all... like this site itself. You just have to be sure to get the entire URL for each unique 'page'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on .asp, so I might be wrong. However, my impression is that a .asp page should ultimately return HTML (similarly to what a .jsp page does), so you can fetch the content in the same way as you would do for an HTML page.

However, you write that

> asp pages seem to have one URL for multiple pages

this makes me think that perhaps your .asp page is using AJAX and so the page content may change while the URL doesn't. Is this your case?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to read the aspx from a client PC, not from the server.

If that's right, accessing an HTTP resource is independent from the technology used by the server, all you need to do is to open an http request and retrieve the results.

If you see multiple pages from one URL, then one of the following is happening:

1) POST data is sent to the aspx, and it renders different HTML due to these parameters

2) You are not looking really at the inner page but to a page that provides the frames for the HTML being rendered

3) The page uses heavily Ajax in order to be rendered. The "contents" of the page are not download through the initial request but later by javascript.

Generally, it is probably the first reason.